# How do I use Tipfy and wsgi_intercept together for testing?

Tags: unit-testing, google-app-engine, testing, wsgi, tipfy

I'm creating an API using [Tipfy](http://www.tipfy.org). I have an existing suite that tests some methods I will expose via URL, but what I'd like to do is see exactly how these functions will work once they're exposed. I'd like to test the URL params directly, for example.

I think what I need is something like [wsgi_intercept](http://code.google.com/p/wsgi-intercept/). It uses a function that 
**returns a WSGI app** to run its tests so you don't have to run a web server in parallel; it bootstraps it for you in the `setUp` function. There's an example at http://ivory.idyll.org/articles/twill-and-wsgi_intercept.html, but I'm not sure how to do it with Tipfy.

What call to the Tipfy library will return the WSGI application itself? `Tipfy.wsgi_app`?

If there is another testing strategy or tool that you can suggest, I'd also appreciate that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **easy_install** to install **wsgi_intercept**, then get hold of the Tipfy app via `make_wsgi_app`.

```
import config
import tipfy 
app = tipfy.make_wsgi_app(config.config)

# Enable the interception of HTTP calls.
from wsgi_intercept.urllib2_intercept import install_opener
install_opener() 
wsgi_intercept.add_wsgi_intercept('localhost', 8000, lambda: app)
```